# How to bring app to Foreground in calabash-android?

Tags: android, ruby, automated-tests, calabash, calabash-android

I am working on a application, it contain social share options. Whenever I tap on facebook it will open facebook app in the device with share view.

After that, I want to bring my application to foreground.

I tried pressing back button,

```
press_back_button()
```

it is unsuccessful.

**Is there any way to bring application to foreground in Calabash-android?**

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do it by sending keypresses and screen touches with ADB

`adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH` to open the recent apps menu
`adb shell input tap 300 300`

Will send a tap event on the screen but you'll have to play around with the coordinates to get them in the right place.

EDIT:
I just tried on my phone with the following commands and can reopen the most recent app

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH
adb shell input tap 300 1700
```

Before trying these commands on your ruby code see if they work from the terminal (not irb).

The second command uses x and y coordinates that will be different depending on the size of the screen on your phone, 300 1700 works for me but you will need to try some different numbers to make it work for you.

To open the second most recent app, which I think is what you will need, I have to run `adb shell input tap 300 700`.  You will need to play around with this and see what works for you.

FINAL EDIT: I've found a nicer way to do this that's not dependant on screen resolution.

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH
```

Then to find your app (you may need to send these multiple times to get it to work)

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_DPAD_UP
```

and/or

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN
```

Then to select

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_ENTER
```

Comment: thanks. I have tried this code in calabash console. It shows following error `NameError: uninitialized constant KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH`

Comment: Hey, in ruby to run a command line you need to put it between backticks ( ` )  EDIT: There are some other ways too but this one should do you for now.

Comment: Do you have the location of adb added to your path?  If you don't then the command would be c:/path/to/adb shell input ......  you can just run these commands from a terminal to check if they work.  I just tried the command on my phone and it worked fine...

Comment: I will edit my answer with 2 command lines that I just tried on my phone and they did work to open the most recent app.

Comment: I've made (hopefully) the last edit to my answer.  It gives a solution that doesn't depend on screen resolution.

Comment: I will check this answer within few days. & let u know.

Answer (score 1):

you need to run the system command, e.g. 
system("adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH”)
This willl open recent activities.